# Feature with different scope for different webapps

Tags: sharepoint

Can a feature in sharepoint have a webapplication scope in one webapp say WApp1
and sitecollection scope in another webapp say WApp2.
If yes , how?

Answer (score 2):

No.

And if you have WebApplication scope of feature, then you can choose to activate it on 1 web app, but not on other.

But you can for sure create 2 features - 1 scoped at WebApplication, the second at Site.